# How do I convert letters to their corresponding number value?

Tags: python, letter

I am relatively new to python. As a mini-project, I am creating a program that involves taking one-word two strings and converting each character to their corresponding letter value (e.g A = 1, C = 3, Z = 26). I want to find a way to do this without assigning all 26 letters to a number in a dictionary. Every algorithm I have found online doesn't seem to be working or I don't understand it.

I am completely lost on how to go about this. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: See [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example...

```
letter = 'c'
print(ord(letter)-96)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ascii code. For example:

```py
num = ord(letter1.lower()) - ord('a') + 1
```

each character is represented by a number in [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/).
You can convert your letter to ascii code using `ord`, and subtract from it the ascii code of letter 'a'. All alphabet is sequential in ascii table. I added `.lower()` since you should split it by two cases, if you have upper case or lower case.
Full code will look something like this (given a letter in variable `letter1`:

```py
if letter`.islower():
   num = ord(letter1) - ord('a') + 1
else:
   num = ord(letter1) - ord('A') + 1
```

(the +1 is if your start counting from 1 rather then 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `ord` function to return the unicode code point (as an integer) for any character.

```
>>> ord('A')
65
```

You can subtract an offset from that if you like.

```
>>> offset = ord('A') - 1
>>> ord('A') - offset
1
>>> ord('B') - offset
2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here:

```
string = 'hello'
nums = ''

for l in string:
    nums += str(ord(l)-96)+' '

print(nums)
```

The ord() function returns an integer representing the Unicode character.
For example, 'a' in Unicode character is 96, 'b' is 97 and 'c' is 98.

Comment: this answer would be improved with a brief description of what `ord` does.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord`:

```
A='lksdfj'
for c in A:
    print(c,':',ord(c))
```

Output:

```
l : 108
k : 107
s : 115
d : 100
f : 102
j : 106
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `string` module provides strings containing the alphabet. You can use a one-liner to make a dict from letter to number:

```
import string
letter_to_number = {l:n+1 for (l,n) in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)))}
# {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9, 'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12, 'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17, 'R': 18, 'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24, 'Y': 25, 'Z': 26}
```